# HTTP 500 error while accessing the application

Tags: java, jsp, nullpointerexception

I am trying to migrate an application which is running on 2008 Windows to 2012 servers.
The application requires Tomcat , Oracle 12c, java, jakarta connector and using IIS .

I am not a developer and therefore unable to find the issue here as its giving null pointer exception .

Can someone guide me on where i am going wrong of if its the code issue. It's a legacy application built many years ago ,so i have less details on code and how it was setup.

[image: Error]
[image]

Comment: You have got `NullPointerException` .  Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) post for more details.

Comment: Can you please post the stack trace as text instead of an image of it?

Comment: Can you please also post your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you are lucky, the reason will be in the config or something like.
You can to get .class file of NationalitySingleton from /tomcat/webapps/..

developer will decompile this file (just drag and drop file to ide) and will try to say reason